# Enable javascript and cookies to continue in postman Api call

Tags: javascript, flutter, postman, coingecko

Im trying to call coingecko api ,it runs on browser and give below issue in postman and api call in flutter.

[image]

[image]

How to add javascript in postman and api call in flutter

Api Url :  https://www.coingecko.com/price_charts/975/usd/24_hours.json

I have tired syncing cookies and javascript , it wont worked

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.